# maxLength attribute of numberfield in sencha touch

Tags: uitextfield, extjs, maxlength

I write a code something like

```
{
   xtype:'numberfield',
   maxLength: 3
}
```

But max-length doesn't work for me any one have any suggestion and any alternate of `maxLength` attribute as in `numberfield` config I can see `maxLength` attribute in sencha touch docs but I don't understand why its not working in my case.

Also it work if I write `textfield` instead of `numberfield`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work well even on Sencha Touch 2, you have to do some workaround `listener`:

```
listeners: {
     keyup: function(textfield, e, eOpts) {
         var value = textfield.getValue() + '';
         var length = value.length;

         console.log(value + ' len: ' + length);

         if (length > MAX_LENGTH) {
             textfield.setValue(value.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH));
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
```

However, doesn't work quite well when the browser formats the number with thousand separators or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug in sencha touch library
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?120818-OPEN-718-NumberField-bug&highlight=maxLength

Comment: this problem seems to be fixed in Sencha touch 2, so can you try to upgrade the library if possible ?